# Reading NSUserDefaults in watchOS 2 (I know App Groups doesn't work)

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, watchkit, watchos-2

Apple documentation says **"Also, iOS automatically forwards a read-only copy of your iOS app’s preferences to Apple Watch. Your WatchKit extension can read those preferences using an NSUserDefaults object..."**. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH29-SW1

But I can't *read* defaults in my WatchKit app that were saved in my iPhone app, am I doing something wrong?

In the WatchKit app, can I even save to (a WatchKit only) defaults, or does that not even work?

iPhone `Data`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(dataArray, forKey: "DataSaved"
```

Watch `ExtensionDelegate`:

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
print(defaults.arrayForKey("DataSaved"))
print(defaults.objectForKey("DataSaved"))
```

`arrayForKey` and `objectForKey` for print `nil`.

I must be doing something wrong, do you know what it would be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Difference between `NSUserDefaults`**

`NSUserDefaults` is a unit of memory on any device, so it is completely different in iOS and watchOS, as well in tvOS, etc.

For example, if you run a code that adds a new key called "key1" to `NSUserDefaults` on iOS (assuming you are using `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`) , when you request to read its data on watchOS, it gives you an empty dictionary.

That's because it the first time, you store the dictionary **only in iOS App Target** and not in a shared space between two devices. When the WatchKit extension wants to use `NSUserDefaults`, it reads the (empty) dictionary saved in WatchKit Target and not the (filled) dictionary in iOS Target.

**Sharing Data**

There are some ways of sharing dictionaries between watchOS and iOS:

1- Using `WatchConnectivity` framework in watchOS 2, you could pass data between two targets. You can use `sendMessage` or similar functions in `WCSession` classes to do so. Just don't forget to add `WCSessionDelegate` to your `InterfaceController` (in watchOS) or `ViewController` (in iOS) classes and app delegates for the app to be able to receive data from `WatchConnectivity`.

2- Using online/cloud storages, you could upload the dictionary from iOS App there, and then download it to watchOS App. However, this needs an Internet connection, and is not suitable in many cases, for example if your app does not need to connect to the Internet to do other tasks, and you force the user to connect to the Internet just in order to sync a simple dictionary between the two targets.

3- Using App Groups (if you are using watchOS 1), which I don't describe it more, because it is outdated and you probably don't want to make your app just for watchOS 1.

Conclusion

1- `NSUserDefaults` returns two different dictionaries in watchOS and iOS, respectively.

2- To share data between watchOS and iOS, you could use `WatchConnectivity`, the Internet (not recommended) and App Groups (in watchOS 1).

**More Resources**

For more details about `WatchConnectivity`, the modern answer to your question, you should check out Apple Documentation in [Apple Developer Portal](http://developer.apple.com).

Also you should see [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/713/) talking about this great framework included in watchOS 2.

Comment: "NSUserDefaults returns two different dictionaries in watchOS and iOS, respectively." was the part I needed thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad that I could solve your problem.

Comment: this answer is lack of information. In [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/SharingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH29-SW1): `Additionally, iOS automatically forwards a read-only copy of your iOS app’s preferences to Apple Watch. Your WatchKit extension can read those preferences using an NSUserDefaults object, but it cannot make changes directly to the defaults database`

Comment: @transang, have you actually seen this behavior? I see that doc as well but I can't see any evidence it is actually true from my experience with watchOS.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. You can't read any defaults in WatchKit app, because from watchOS2 it has it's own memory to be used. so You can not access value from iOS's NSUserDefaults in watchOS

You have to use WatchConnectivity to share data for watch OS2.

Comment: I think you referenced a prerelease version of watch os, so it might not be accurate now.

Comment: @NicolasS ah, I see.  Do you know if there is an updated doc of that, because I don't see anything about NSUserDefaults that has been updated since then that I can find.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To be clear, `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` will give you two different dictionaries when calling on the watch and on the phone.

For WatchConnectivity check out https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/713/

Apple docs:

https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WatchConnectivity_framework/index.html

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea.  Do you have the Apple Doc that references that, or something else that references that, so I can start to wrap my head around how that works?

Comment: I don't see anything about NSUserDefaults there?

Comment: WatchConnectivity won't give you access to the NSUserDefaults.

However, from within your phone app, you could use WatchConnectivity to send a copy of the defaults to your watch app. The watch app could use the received object, and if changes need to be made, send the changes back to the phone app. The phone app could then write those changes to it's NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @JoshBuhler the problem I'm having is that I'll save and object to NSUserDefaults on iPhone and then not be able to read that object on Watch. I can't do this "The watch app could use the received object" when I've tried it, but being able to do that is what I'm hoping to do

Comment: @victorpulak Have you tried sending data from your phone to the watch using WCSession and the sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler message? What happens when you do that?

Comment: I was putting this question up so I could find out specifically about the NSUserDefaults part of the equation.  I have used all the Watch Connectivity, and was just looking for specific docs on how NSUserDefaults does or doesn't work, since I see conflicting information when I research it.  Appreciate the help, if you see anything on NSUserDefaults just let me know

Comment: You need to use watch connectivity transferUserInfo on the dictionary you get from NSUserDefaults on the phone now.  The NSUserDefaults will not be transferred for you anymore in watchOS 2.  You can write them to the watch NSUserDefaults yourself though.

Comment: @Cobra the last sentence was exactly what I was looking for thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ns defaults.standard is particular to that target by using it you can access data within that target, in your case you need to access data in another target so listen you need to do two things one is 
1. use app groups 
2. don't use user defaults.standard use UserDefaults(suiteName:"group.yourgroup")
to store and access the data 
refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnxzUayiNrs) Link might be useful.